# How is this histogram correct?

Tags: statistics, visualization

Looking at this histogram in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram#Examples)(one on the right and not the ones at the bottom), I am unable to understand how it is correct or is there a flaw in my understanding.

```
Bin   Count
−3.5     23
−2.5     32
−1.5    109
−0.5    180
 0.5    132
 1.5     34
 2.5      4
 3.5     90
```

Given the above information, I can infer that the bins are -:

-3.5 to less than 2.5

-2.5 to less than -1.5

and so on.

Is this inference correct or am I missing something here ?

If the above inference is correct then the looking at the first column is for 23 values occurring in the first bin.

What is weird is the last bin(for 3.5, the last element in the table) for which there are 90 values in the table **but the values shown in the histogram are lesser than the 23 values in the first column.**

How is that possible ? Is that correct ? Or are my concepts lacking somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data appears to have been corrupted across the various [Wiki sites](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Example_histogram.png).

For example, the same page on the Swedish site:

> [Swedish Wikipedia:Histogram](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram)

uses different data and different bins.

I have updated the [English wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).